# Unable to set custom icon on application launcher

Tags: icons, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and having trouble setting a custom icon for an application launcher that I created.  I have created and SVG file and placed it in `/usr/shared/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/` and when I try to select it as the icon for the application launcher, it just goes back to the gnome-panel-launcher.svg default.

If I put the SVG file on my desktop and then select it, all is well.  I'm assuming this is some type of permission problem, but I cannot seem to figure it out.  I have set the permissions to be identical to the other icons in `/usr/shared/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/`, but have no luck doing that either.

Comment: Did you verify that YOUR user has read/write permissions to the scalable/apps folder? i mean same user, group, chmod permissions, chown permission. just to be 100% sure.

Comment: @CYREX Your user does not need to have write permissions to any icon folder to use the icon in a launcher.

Comment: @CYREX all of the icons and folders are owned by root, which is the default, and I am able to set any of the other icons for the application launcher.

Comment: You are able to set any of the icons in that folder except for the one you want to use? which was added by you?

Comment: @Jared, how exactly did you put the icon in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps`?

Comment: @CYREX First time I did `sudo cp myicon.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/`. Then I did `gksudo nautilus` and copied it that way. Neither way worked for me.

Comment: It may have something to do with the icon-finding behaviour.  If you specify an icon in /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/ (and possibly other folders under apps/), it will search for that icon name in your current theme; I don't know what happens if it can't find it.  What happens if you put it in /usr/share/pixmaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you also need to Provide PNG versions in 16x16,24x24,36x36,48x48 ect. folders. Not just scalable! Maybe you can try the ubuntu-mono-light and ubuntu-mono-dark folders :)

Comment: That seems to have worked.  I didn't verify that you must also provide the PNG versions, but by placing it in a different folder, I was able to set the custom icon.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No Problem I like to help :)

Comment: FYI I also had to grant full read permissions in order to get this to work (gou+r)

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with .png, but a 64x64 .jpg worked! (Ubuntu Trusty, Gnome)

YMMV, so this is what my system is:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"

Linux *** 4.4.0-83-generic #106~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:10:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

GNOME Shell 3.10.4
```

I had to kill `gnome-panel` to see the new icons on the panel:

```
ps aux | grep gnome-panel
```

shows you the PID:

```
me        2397  0.0  0.3 738108 56688 ?        Sl   Nov30   2:39 gnome-panel
me       22210  0.0  0.0  18420  2100 pts/43   S+   13:16   0:00 grep --color=auto gnome-panel
```

and

```
kill 2397
```

does the trick. The killed panel automatically restarts in seconds.